# Device Driver's ImagePath

Tags: windows, windows-services, device-driver, smb

I always set my drivers Imagepath directly.(C:\Windows\System32\drivers\abc.sys)

But I just knew many device drivers set their ImagePath to ***%SystemRoot%\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs***
[image]
This is Lanmanworkstation driver's registry hive.
I guess Lanmanworkstation driver's image file is mrxsmb.sys
But they didn't put 'System32\drivers\mrxsmb.sys'. Why.

What does *svchost.exe -k netsvcs* mean?
Even though there is no certain path, StartService function works well.
How does Service Manager(? i'm not sure) find the driver's image path?

Is there an advantage using this?
What if I decide to use this way, are there my driver codes should modify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing between device drivers and services.
svchost.exe is used to share the same process between multiple services.  The implementation is internal to Windows so use outside of Windows is not supported.

If you write a device driver (for hardware, or a filter driver) or do not work for Microsoft, you cannot use svchost.

The reason for the confusion is because old style (NT4), non-plug-and-play drivers can be started using the Service Control Manager APIs.

Comment: I'm writing a device driver like Lanmanager.(network redirector). I thought Lanmanworkstation is SMB redirector's registry key. I'm not sure now. Am I wrong?

Comment: lanmanworkstation is the Workstation service, the driver is called Mrxsmb.sys.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939966.aspx

Comment: Note that you *cannot* use svchost to share the same process between multiple services (unless you work in the Windows division at Microsoft (and even then there are very strict rules that have to be followed)).  The architecture of svchost is 100% internal to Windows and the interfaces between svchost and its hosted services may change without warning at any time.

Comment: Aha, I guess now, the workstation service launches Mrxsmb.sys using StartService().

Answer (score 1):

*svchost.exe* is a "multi-purpose" service. It incorporates multiple services in one single exe file, each of which can be seperately controlled using e.g. services management console. The parameters to svchost.exe states the "subservice" inside the exe file.

As startService() is not a control message to the service itself but instead only the request to start a certain executable (which itself must "know" that it is a service (and wich service) and will then register with service control manager), windows will simply execute the binary that `ImagePath` points to.

In this case (LanManWorkstation) this binary is `svchost.exe`, the parameter given to it is `-k netsvc`. This lets svchost.exe know which of the many service it provides should be started.

As usual, the binary doesn't need to contain all the function in itself but can also load additional libraries. `mrxsmb.sys` may well be such a library, though I'm not sure of this point.

So this answer is more of a "how does it work in general" than a "yes, netsvc and mrxsmb.sys are LanManWorkstation".

Answer (score 1):

svchost is a host process for other services, contained in DLLs. The part after the "-k" indicates the service group. You can find the service DLL path in `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters` in the `ServiceDll` value. I'm guessing the reason it still starts correctly if you remove the image path is because the service type is set to `SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS`, and the SCM probably ignores the image path (not sure about this).